# RTOS SDK Where is app_main defined as startup function?

Tags: sdk, esp8266, esp32, rtos

Using rtos SDK i was able to develop and run successfully some simple examples, but I need to understand.

Normally a c / c++ program starts with main(...) (I don't remember the exact signature)

RTOS projects seem to start almost all with app_main() and some examples online with user_init()

A text search throughout all sources did not help me. It seems that there is a startup.c that in turn calls app_main but this does not explain why some **other** examples (https://github.com/espressif/esp8266-rtos-sample-code/blob/master/03Wifi/Soft_AP_DEMO/user/user_main.c that I did not try) have another entrypoint.

Can somebody explain how it is structured? "Who" is
calling app_main?

Comment: look into ```components/esp32/cpu_start.c``` and ```components/esp8266/source/startup.c```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ESP32 ESP-IDF SDK startup procedure is fairly thoroughly described in [Application Startup Flow - Application startup](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/startup.html#application-startup). ESP8266 RTOS SDK startup is similar.

> ESP-IDF application entry point is `call_start_cpu0` function found in
> [components/esp_system/port/cpu_start.c](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/83956eb/components/esp_system/port/cpu_start.c). This function is executed by
> the second stage bootloader, and never returns.
>
> . . . <skip> . . .
>
> Once `call_start_cpu0` completes running, it calls the “system layer”
> initialization function `start_cpu0` found in
> [components/esp_system/startup.c](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/83956eb/components/esp_system/startup.c). Other cores will also complete
> port-layer initialization and call `start_other_cores` found in the same
> file.
>
> . . . <skip> . . .
>
> The main system initialization function is
> `start_cpu0`. By default, this function is weak-linked to the function
> `start_cpu0_default`. This means that it’s possible to override this
> function to add some additional initialization steps.
>
> . . . <skip> . . .
>
> After all other components are initialized, the main task is created and the FreeRTOS scheduler starts running.
>
> After doing some more initialization tasks (that require the scheduler
> to have started), the main task runs the application-provided function
> `app_main` in the firmware.

The last part has been refactored recently. [Here's](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/v4.2.2/components/esp32/cpu_start.c#L609) a link to the `app_main` call in an older IDF-SDK v4.2.